# How to pass selected id to modal in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to delete user with popup alert. I have list of users. When i click on delete button i want to pass id to modal through method and then that id to delete method which is calling on button in modal. I'm getting error *Property or method "id" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render*. How i can get the id of clicked user?

Table

```
<tr v-for="users in pending_users.data" :key="users.id">
   <td>{{users.name}}</td>
   <td>{{users.email}}</td>
   <td>{{users.mobile_no}}</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="showModal(users.id)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Modal

```
       <div class="modal fade" id="userDeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
             aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete or Decline user</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Do you want to delete this user?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="deleteUser(id)">Yes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Methods

```
<script>
     export default {
        data() {
            return {

           }
        },
        methods: {
            showModal(id) {
                $('#userDeleteModal').modal('show');
            },
            deleteUser(id) {
              axios.post('api/deleteUser', null,
             {
                params: {
                    'user_id': id,
                        }
             })
             .then(({data}) => {

                    });

            },

        },

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your passing id, so you just need to define it on a model somewhere so deleteUser can pick it up

```
export default {
   data() {
       return {
           editing_user_id: 0,
           //..
       }
   },
   methods:{
       showModal(id) {
            this.editing_user_id = id;
            $('#userDeleteModal').modal('show');
        },
        deleteUser() { 
          axios.post('api/deleteUser', null, {
            params: {
                'user_id': this.editing_user_id,

        //..
   }
```

---

IMO just pass the whole item/user i.e `showModal(user)`, then change `editing_user_id` to just `editing_user` your almost always want more than just the id.

and aim for `axios.delete('api/user/' + editing_user.id, ...` it makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks now i can delete clicked item but i'm getting same error on console *Property or method "id" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render*. why it is coming?

Comment: on your modal `id="userDeleteModal"` you use id on deleteUser, but it not defined, add a `v-if="id"` to that button, as said if you use just deleteUser without passing an id as shown above, it will work.